# dataframe.isin using multiple OR operators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operators

I want to see if I have some values from a list in multiple columns from my pandas dataframe.

Basically, I want to look over my column A, B and C if the values from a list exists and if so filter the rows where those values exist.
For that I am using this:

```
processes = ['process_A', 'process_B']
df[df.col_A.isin(processes),df.col_B.isin(processes), df.col_C.isin(processes)].any()
```

And already try this:

```
df[df.col_A.isin(processes) OR df.col_B.isin(processes) or df.col_C.isin(processes)]
```

But I got a lot of errors or unexpectables results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.isin` returns a boolean Series, you need to use `|` for logical OR between the values.

try this:

```py
df[df.col_A.isin(processes) | df.col_B.isin(processes) | df.col_C.isin(processes)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `any` as below

```
df[df[['col_A','col_B','col_C']].isin(processes).any(1)]
```